# Map a java class to Postgresql table error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I try to create a Student entity in java using JPA, but something not work.

I have a table in postgresql named "Studenti" and class Student

My student class is:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity(name = "Student")
@Table(name = "Studenti")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private long Id;

    @Column(name = "Nume")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "Prenume")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "An")
    private int year;

    @Column(name = "Id_cont")
    private long accountId;
}
```

And the table has the following structure:

[image]

Application.properties:

```
server.port=9091

spring.application.name=user-management

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Licenta
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*****

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Need to crete a special file with setting for this or something else ?

Comment: A `uuid` is not a `long`. I would suspect that this is the problem. Can you please include the stack trace you encounter?

Comment: please specify @GeneratedValue for the id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can configure PostgreSQL connection only in application.properties file

Maybe few more configuration parameters, especially this

```
spring.datasource.driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver
```

If you already have a DB structure, better set `ddl-auto=none`

And PostgreSQL has Oracle engine (or like Oracle engine) so for @Id field better to use sequences

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "genname")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "genname", sequenceName = "seqname", allocationSize = 1)
```

And @Id field must not be a primitive, just Long, Integer, String, UUID or other possible implementation.